# Scala implicit final class

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

I'm trying to create a way to add days to a LocalDate object in Scala through implicit classes, but I continually get an error either saying "LocalDate is a final class and cannot be extended" or below:

`scala:73: could not find implicit value for parameter year: Int`

Here's the code I tried using:

```
 implicit class UVMLocalDate(val me: Int) extends AnyVal{

 implicit def days(implicit year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
 LocalDate.of(year,month,me + days)
 }

 }
```

I'm restricted to having the class behave like so:

`(LocalDate.of(2015, 4, 14)) == (LocalDate.of(2015, 4, 12) + 2.days)`

Example use:

```
val dateEx = LocalDate.of(2015, 3, 23) + 2.days
assert(dateEx == LocalDate.of(2015, 3, 25))
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using java.time? In that case, you can't add 2 `LocalDate`s together. It also doesn't provide a Scala `+` method.

Comment: Also you are taking in 3 implicit Int arguments to your "days" method, implicit arguments are resolved by type so you would always have the same value for all 3 arguments.

Comment: I can't find much connection between the implicit class pasted and the way you want it to behave.

Comment: Please rephrase the question. Providing an example of the code which would use this new `days` method would be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a mixture of features from `scala.concurrent.duration._` and `org.joda.time._`.

It does not really make sense to add a date to another date and `2.days` is not really a *date* but rather a *duration*. You could go ahead and re-invent the wheel by defining a new class for it:

```
class Duration(millis: Long)
object Duration {
  val SecondMillis = 1000
  val MinuteMillis = SecondMillis * 60
  val HourMillis = MinuteMillis * 60
  val DayMillis = HourMillis * 24

  implicit class DurationFromDays(private val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal {
    def days: Duration = new Duration(underlying * DayMillis)
  }
}
```

However, you could just use the API by `scala.concurrent.duration.Duration`.

And then you also need to define an implicit class for adding a `Duration` to a `LocalDate`.

```
implicit class LocalDateOps(private val underlying: LocalDate) extends AnyVal {
  def +(duration: Duration): LocalDate = ???
}
```

However, there are libraries (like *joda-time*) where the functionality to add a duration to a date is already implemented.